# How to install Cluster management feature on Carbon

Tags: wso2

I am learning WSO2 stratos, and trying to setup a Carbon with cluster. I looked at this article http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/install-wso2-carbon-cluster-management-feature, but it seems out-dated, and I could not find Cluster Management in Features. The carbon version I'm using is 4.1.0. Anybody know how to setup the cluster? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new approach of wso2 worker manager separated clustering is described in detail by blog of Azeez [1]

The detail steps can be found from charitha's blog at [2]

[1].http://blog.afkham.org/2012/08/separation-of-worker-management-nodes.html
[2].http://charithaka.blogspot.com/2012/09/setting-up-minimum-deployment-of-wso2.html

Thank You,
Dharshana.